# How to use SURF in Opencv3.1?

Tags: c++, opencv, sift, surf

I have Opencv3.1 and installed together with opencv_contrib.
I can build successfully for the following code.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#define USE_SURF
#define USE_FLANN

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::xfeatures2d;

int imagematching(Mat &first, Mat & second)
{


   return 0;
}
```

That means, my `xfeatures2d` is installed successfully. Then when I include

```
int imagematching(Mat &first, Mat & second)
{
    int max_keypoints = 500;
    Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create( max_keypoints );

    return 0;
}
```

Then I have errors as

```
[100%] Building CXX object FeaturepointsMatching/CMakeFiles/FeaturepointsMatching.dir/featurepoints_matching.cpp.o
/home/Softwares/3D_images/Reconstruction/FeaturepointsMatching/featurepoints_matching.cpp: In function ‘int imagematching(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&)’:
/home/Softwares/3D_images/Reconstruction/FeaturepointsMatching/featurepoints_matching.cpp:14:13: error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be 1)
     Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create( max_keypoints );
             ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:56:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:48,
                 from /home/nyan/Softwares/3D_images/Reconstruction/FeaturepointsMatching/featurepoints_matching.h:3,
                 from /home/Softwares/3D_images/Reconstruction/FeaturepointsMatching/featurepoints_matching.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:283:8: error: provided for ‘template<class T> struct cv::Ptr’
 struct Ptr
        ^
/home/Softwares/3D_images/Reconstruction/FeaturepointsMatching/featurepoints_matching.cpp:14:24: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘=’ token
     Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create( max_keypoints );
                        ^
/home/Softwares/3D_images/Reconstruction/FeaturepointsMatching/featurepoints_matching.cpp:14:30: error: ‘::create’ has not been declared
     Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create( max_keypoints );
                              ^
make[2]: *** [FeaturepointsMatching/CMakeFiles/FeaturepointsMatching.dir/featurepoints_matching.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [FeaturepointsMatching/CMakeFiles/FeaturepointsMatching.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is wrong with SURF in Opencv3.1?
Thanks

Comment: Why are defining SURF ?

Comment: @Vtik  I have updated. It is not used yet.

Comment: Yes that is the problem. Thanks

Comment: I suspected that you edited the code without editing the output !